# class vs static methods

Tags: c#, python, oop

I'm new in Python (come from C#), trying to figure out how OOP works here.
Started from very begining I try to implement `Vector` class.
I want to have basis vectors (i, j, k)  defined in `Vector`class.
In C#, I can do this like that:

```
public class Vector
{
    // fields...
    public Vector(int[] array){
        //...
    }

    public static Vector i(){
        return new Vector(new int[1, 0, 0]);
    }
}
```

Exploring Python I found 2 ways how to implement this: using either `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(array):
        #...

    @classmethod
    def i(self):
        return Vector([1, 0, 0])
```

Since I don't need to have access to any information inside the class, should I really use `@classmethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've confused yourself with your naming of arguments a bit. The first argument a class method receives is the class itself, which would be Vector, for now, until you have a subclass. A class method would be implemented like this:

```
    @classmethod
    def i(cls):
        return cls([1, 0, 0])
```

Generally, an instance method (no decorator) calls its first argument `self`, which is the instance. A class method has `cls`, which is the class, which can be used to construct an instance. A static method takes no "extra" argument, so your other option, if you want to always return a `Vector`, is:

```
    @staticmethod
    def i():
        return Vector([1, 0, 0])
```